# sscanf for formatting string from file

Tags: c, string, output, scanf, imperative

As part of a homework assignment I need to load a file with data in the following format:

```
R1  Fre     17/07/2015   18.00     FCN - SDR     0 - 2     3.211   
R1  Lor     18/07/2015   16.00     FCM - VFF     2 - 0     7.232
```

For doing so I used fgets to store the string in a temporary string and after that sscanf to format the string while iterating through the file line by line.

```
while(fgets(temp, MAX_LINE_SIZE, input_file)!= NULL) {
  sscanf(temp, 
    " %*s %3s %d / %d / %d %s %3s - %3s %d - %d %6s",

    round[i].match[j].weekday, 
    &round[i].match[j].day, 
    ..... And so on ....
  j++;
}
```

Current output is:

```
Weekday: Fre18.00FCNSDR3.211
Day: 17
Month: 7
Year: 2015
Start: 18.00FCNSDR3.211
Home team: FCNSDR3.211
Away team: SDR3.211
Score: 0 - 2
Viewers: 3.211
```

Expected output is:

```
Weekday: Fre
Day: 17
Month: 7
Year: 2015
Start: 18.00
Home team: FCN
Away team: SDR
Score: 0 - 2
Viewers: 3.211
```

The strings with %s placeholder in sscanf seems to putting themselves together for some reason.

All help is **much** appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're storing strings like `Fre` in a 4-byte character array?

`%3s` actually reads in 4 bytes.  `F`, `r`, `e`, and `\0`.  If you use an array too small then you overwrite the `\0`, causing the string to include whatever comes next in memory (in this case, more strings).

Comment: You are completely right. I forgot to allocate enough memory for each string. **Thank you!**